# CSS: border-spacing: and background-image: dont work togeather

Tags: html, css, html-table

Hi I got a table and a background image that I will like to go over the border of the table for 20px.
The problem is that the background sticks to the edge of the test.

index.css

```
.noteback {
  border-spacing: 20px  ; 
  align:center ;
  background-image: url(Images/backGround.png);
  background-repeat:  inherit ;
```

index.htm

```
<table class="noteback" >
     <tr>
        <td>
            Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test.............   
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: `border-spacing` only applies to table and inline-table elements. And there is no `align` property.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, i was trying anything to make it work but haven't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

If you have flat color, use following code

```css
table {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000; /*remove border, it is only for testing purpose*/
}
table td {
  background-color: #000; /*replace color with your image*/
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table class="noteback">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test.............
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or if you have image, use `:before` or `:after`

```css
table {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
table:before {
  content: '';
  background: url(http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/images/Child-Girl-with-Sunflowers-Images.jpg) no-repeat center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
}
table td{
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table class="noteback">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test.............
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please let me know if you need any help :)

Comment: Great, I'm getting closer the the solution!

Comment: The problem is that I will like the background to go over the the text for 20px, instead in this example the image is "cut" next to the texts. Sorry maybe I am not too clear...

Comment: Please check now, you have to add `padding: 20px;` to `td`.

Comment: Thank you so much, now it is working ok, the bootstrap css was interfering with the main css!!!!